# Pass tuple enum to instruction data

Tags: anchor-program-idl

I pass custom struct including tuple enum to instruction:

```
#[derive(Debug, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub enum FeedValue {
    Boolean(bool),
    U8(u8),
    U16(u16),
    U32(u32),
    U64(u64),
    U128(u128),
}

#[derive(Debug, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct Feed {
    /// The value that is stored within a single feed. In most cases, intermediate
    /// nodes or non-leaf feeds will be None (although some may decide to have a
    /// summary value for their children), and leaf feeds will have concrete values.
    pub value: Option<FeedValue>,
}

#[program]
pub mod my_program {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create(ctx: Context<Create>, feed: Feed) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

, and I've got this error:

```
Error: Tuple enum variants not yet implemented.
    at /Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:134:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:132:45
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.typeDefLayout (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:127:44)
    at Function.fieldLayout (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:96:27)
    at Function.fieldLayout (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:77:22)
    at /Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:122:28
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.typeDefLayout (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:121:48)
    at Function.fieldLayout (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:96:27)
    at /Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/instruction.ts:114:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/instruction.ts:113:38
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.parseIxLayout (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/instruction.ts:112:26)
    at new BorshInstructionCoder (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/instruction.ts:47:43)
    at new BorshCoder (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/index.ts:47:24)
    at new Program (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/index.ts:283:28)
    at /Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/workspace.ts:59:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.get (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/workspace.ts:52:10)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/tests/orao-onchain.ts:9:38)
    at Object.create (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:148:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:42:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/tests/orao-onchain.ts:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:60:20)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:103:20)
    at singleRun (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at Object.exports.handler (/Volumes/DATA/SourceCode/orao-network/orao/orao-anchor/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What issue and how to fix?

Comment: can you provide a code snippet of the corresponding TS client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, it is simply not implemented in the anchor typescript client.

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/698426033052781988cd7980249726501ae08bdc/ts/src/coder/common.ts#L13-L15

There are 2 options:

1. Workaround the limitation by not using the feature that isn't implemented

It would look like this

```
#[derive(Debug, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub enum FeedValue {
    Boolean { value: bool},
    U8 { value: u8 },
    U16 { value: u16 },
    ...
```

2. Implement it in anchor with a pull request!